# How do i convert json into csv but with a parent node

Tags: java, json, firebase, export-to-csv

okay i know this is a duplicate but i rally messed up on this topic from last 3 days andnlast question was incomplete

I have the parent node "Quote" in it I have the child nodes but I don't know how can i convert JSON to CSV with a parent node

I searched a lot but I dint find a convincing answer to my issue

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1u6Ul9qblAc5SkGhC2N3-yMmpGqRxmaGP/view?usp=sharing) is the json

How should I proceed

In fact, I am not sure how a parent node should look in a CSV. If you asked me, how do I want the CSV format, I would respond that I don't know, that's why I'm converting JSON to CSV, to find out how the format looks with a parent node. If I know how the CSV format should be, why would I do all this conversion? The main objective is to find out how the CSV format looks.

and one more thing, if it gets converted successfully can I convert it back to JSON after adding some data, will it be like the original one?

Comment: Somebody already tried to show you how to implement this when you [first asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72570697/how-do-i-convert-json-into-csv-but-with-a-parent-node). Instead of reposting, follow up there please.

Comment: The original first question URL is actually [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72551095/how-do-i-convert-this-json-file-to-csv)

Comment: @lepsch  hey please can you please see the comment on that answer please

Comment: @Player91 please check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72600703/2828341). And please, delete this question as it's a duplicate. You can edit the other one with the additional info here.

Comment: The question is tagged with Firebase but this has nothing to do with Firebase - it's a JSON format question so that tag should be removed. More importantly, why do you want to do this in the first place - do you want to import the data into Excel or Numbers? What's the purpose? Have you tried any of the [JSON to CSV converters](https://www.convertcsv.com/json-to-csv.htm)?

Comment: @Jay thank you to all, I've managed to get the desired output, with this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72600703/18105926